# Problem running aspnet core project on macos

Tags: c#, macos, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I want to run a backend API in ASP.NET Core on a macos, the project was developed on Windows machines so there was used IIs Express to run it, but i don't know what I need to change to have it run on macos.

I found that IIs Express don't work on macos, so I need to use some alternative as I think

Comment: ASP.NET Core comes with its own cross-platform local webserver you can use immediately - and that webserver is the default for development anyway - so if the project is using IIS Express then it might be because the project depends on IIS-specific behaviour or functionality (such as `web.config` and `<rewrite>`). What does your project's onboarding documentation say?

Comment: the readme file doesn't says much only "just run the app", can be mockserver causing this problem?

Comment: Does the project have a `web.config` file? If not, then remove the entries from `launchSettings.json` that reference IIS Express. VS-for-Mac can also regenerate new launch configurations for your machine too.

Comment: it does not have web.config file but launchSettings.json has. I am using Rider on mac, but will try to delete this file like you have written and make it run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer this blog to run your application.

[How to Build Cross-Platform .NET Core Apps](https://stackify.com/cross-platform-net-core-apps/)

I have tried to create a app in windows, then copy it to macos. I can run it successfully in macos by using visual studio mac, and also tried in Rider. You also can using the dotnet-cli to start the application.

According to the official doc, it suggests to [using Nginx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-nginx?tabs=linux-ubuntu&view=aspnetcore-7.0).